# Error for saving a record from a POS program

Tags: c++, fstream, dev-c++, point-of-sale

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string saveload;
int numProducts=0;
int counter=1;
int product;
double payment1;
double change=0;
double subtotal=0;
double payment=0;
int n;
string Id;
int option;
const char* products[] = {"Cardinal Steak w/ drink and dessert", "Cardinal Grilled Chicken w/ drink and dessert",
 "Cardinal Bangus w/ drink and dessert", "Mathematician Burger w/ drink and dessert", 
 "Cardinal Spring Rolls w/ drink and dessert", "Cardinal Steak", "Cardinal Grilled Chicken", "Cardinal Bangus",
 "Mathematician Burger", "Cardinal Spring Rolls", "Sweet Mapuan Potato", "Wedged Mapuan Potato",
 "Mashed Math Potato w/ gravy", "Physics Special Salad", "Chemistry Hot wings Special", "Sinko Shake",
 "Banofee", "Korean shaved ice with sugar, fruit syrup", "Nigerian Pepper Soup", "Sudanese Basbosa"};
 double prices[] = {450, 400, 200, 250, 350, 300, 280, 140, 130, 150, 80, 90, 60, 40, 100, 55, 60, 77, 77, 85};
 int items[100];

cout<<setw(120)<<"Organic Food Chain"<<endl;
cout<<"Please enter your Id"<<endl;
cout<<"Id: ";
cin>>Id;
if(Id=="a")
{
    cout<<"Password: *******"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Order"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Show the record"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Log out"<<endl;
    cout<<"Choose: ";
    cin>>option;
    cout<<endl;
        if(option==1)
        {

            cout<<"How many products are you ordering?: ";
            cin>>numProducts;

            for(n = 0;n<numProducts;n++)
            {
            cout<<"Combo"<<endl;
            cout<<"1.Cardinal Steak w/ drink and dessert Php450"<<endl;
            cout<<"2.Cardinal Grilled Chicken w/ drink and dessert Php400"<<endl;
            cout<<"3.Cardinal Bangus w/ drink and dessert Php200"<<endl;
            cout<<"4.Mathematician Burger w/ drink and dessert Php250"<<endl;
            cout<<"5.Cardinal Spring Rolls w/ drink and dessert Php350"<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"Alacarte"<<endl;
            cout<<"6.Cardinal Steak Php300"<<endl;
            cout<<"7.Cardinal Grilled Chicken Php280"<<endl;
            cout<<"8.Cardinal Bangus Php140"<<endl;
            cout<<"9.Mathematician Burger Php130"<<endl;
            cout<<"10.Cardinal Spring Rolls Php150"<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"Sidedish"<<endl;
            cout<<"11.Sweet Mapuan Potato Php80"<<endl;
            cout<<"12.Wedged Mapuan Potato Php90"<<endl;
            cout<<"13.Mashed Math Potato w/ gravy Php60"<<endl;
            cout<<"14.Physics Special Salad Php40"<<endl;
            cout<<"15.Chemistry Hot wings Special Php100"<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"Drink & Dessert"<<endl;
            cout<<"16.Sinko Shake Php55"<<endl;
            cout<<"17.Banofee Php60"<<endl;
            cout<<"18.Korean shaved ice with sugar, fruit syrup  Php77"<<endl;
            cout<<"19.Nigerian Pepper Soup Php77"<<endl;
            cout<<"20.Sudanese Basbosa Php85"<<endl;

            do{
            cout <<"Enter your selection: ";
            cin>>product;
            cout<<endl;
        }while(product < 1 || product > 20);

        items[n]=product-1;
        }
        subtotal=0;
for(n=0;n<numProducts;n++)
{
    cout<<left<<setw(25)<<products[items[n]]; 
    cout<<right<<setw(10)<<prices[items[n]]<<endl;
    subtotal=subtotal+prices[items[n]];
}

cout<<right;
cout<<"-----------------------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"Total:  "<<setw(24)<<subtotal<<endl;
do{
cout<<"Please make payment: ";
cin>>payment1;
payment=payment+payment1;
if(payment > subtotal)
{
    change=payment-subtotal;
    cout<<"Your change is: "<<change;
    ofstream out("save.txt");
cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf()); 
cout<<left<<setw(25)<<products[items[n]]; 
    cout<<right<<setw(10)<<prices[items[n]]<<endl;
    subtotal=subtotal+prices[items[n]];
    cout<<right;
cout<<"-----------------------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"Total:  "<<setw(24)<<subtotal<<endl;
cout<<"Please make payment: "<<payment;
cout<<"Your change is: "<<change;

}
}while((payment-subtotal) < 0);    
    }
    if(option==2);

            }
else
{
    cout<<"Please enter the correct Id";
}
return 0;
}
```

I made the first few sentences but inside if statements I just followed one of the POS program in the net. The problem is that I have to save and load the record but I can not save it. The part that Im going to save is where the code 
     ofstream out("save.txt");
     cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf()); 
You can totally erase this statement as long as I can save those information. For additional can you add there how to load?? Though it is not complete yet, I just need to know how to save and load the record in this program. please help. Thank you very much. By the way I am using Dev C++ ver.5.5.1.

Comment: It will be helpful to reduce the program to a smaller program so the problem can be duplicated easily.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you eliminate trying to tie two streams and print the data twice, once to `cout` and once to the file.

### Simplifying output by using structure.

You can simplify your output of a data record by using a function, or method, that takes a record (structure item).  You could pass different streams to the function rather than duplicating code.  But it all boils down to using a structure.

Let's group the items into a structure:

```
struct POS_Item // Point of Sale item
{
  double price;
  std::string description;
  unsigned int product_id;
};
```

Let's initialize a structure instance.

```
 POS_Item item; // create an instance

 // Initialize the item.
 item.price = 24
 item.description = "Mathematician Burger";
 item.product_id = 3;
```

### Output a POS Item:

And create a function to output the item:

```
void output_item(std::ostream& out, const POS_Item& item)
{
  out << item.id << ". " << item.description << "   Php " << item.price << "\n";
}
```

To output the item to a file:

```
  output_item(out, item);
```

To output the item to the console:

```
  output_item(std::cout, item);
```

### A Container of POS items:

Since the POS details are in a structure, you can have one container for all the records:

```
std::vector<POS_Item> item_container;
```

Adding an item to the container:

```
  item.id = 26;
  item.description = "Omelete";
  item.price = 24;
  item_container.push_back(item);
```

Output all the items in the container to a file:

```
  std::vector<POS_Item>::const_iterator iter;
  for (iter =  item_container.begin();
       iter != item_container.end();
     ++iter)
  {
    output_item(out, *iter);
  }
```

Using a structure will simplify your code making it easier to write and debug.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort explanation. Still it will take time for me to understand what you said since Im just a beginner but thank you very much again, Im sure it will help me a lot in my program hahaha